# Proof: $C(X×Y)=C(X)⊗C(Y)$

Tags: analysis, operator-algebras

Where I can find the proof of the following theorem:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact Hausdorff spaces, $C(X)$ and $C(Y)$ the space of continuous functions on $X$ and $Y$ respectively, then we have $C(X×Y)=C(X)⊗C(Y)$.

Comment: Try to do it directly from definition.

Comment: Btw, what kind of tensor product is that?

Comment: Before other people also claim that this is an easy statement: 1) This is not true for the tensor product of vector spaces. We need a completed tensor product of Banach spaces. There are various choices, but here in fact any works (since commutative C*-algebras are nuclear ...). 2) It is easy to construct a map $C(X) \widehat{\otimes} C(Y)  \to C(X \times Y)$, but it is not trivial that it is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that by $A \otimes B$ you mean the [maximal tensor product](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximales_Tensorprodukt) of two C*-algebras $A,B$ (which is a completion of the tensor product of the underlying vector spaces). Let us restrict to the unital case. Then there are homomorphisms of C*-algebras $\iota_A : A \to A \otimes B$, $a \mapsto a \otimes 1$ and $\iota_B : B \to A \otimes B$, $b \mapsto 1 \otimes b$ which commute (i.e. $\iota_A(a)$ commutes with $\iota_B(b)$ for every $a \in A$, $b \in B$), and these are universal with respect to this property: If $f : A \to C$ and $g : B \to C$ are homomorphisms of unital $C^*$-algebras which commute, then there is a unique homomorphism $h : A \otimes B \to C$ of unital $C^*$-algebras such that $h \circ \iota_A = f$ and $h \circ {\iota_B} = g$.

It follows that if $A,B$ are commutative, then also $A \otimes B$ is commutative, and it is the [coproduct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct) of $A$ and $B$ in the category of commutative unital C*-algebras.

The category of compact Hausdorff spaces is equivalent to the dual of the category of commutative unital C*-algebras - via the functor given by $X \mapsto C(X)$ on objects and by $f \mapsto f^*$ on morphisms ([commutative Gelfand-Naimark Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation)). Every equivalence of categories preserves products, and products in a dual category correspond to coproducts. This proves $C(X \times Y) \cong C(X) \otimes C(Y)$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Is that $C(X×Y)≅C(X)⊗C(Y)$ still valid if we take infinite products instead of just two?

Comment: How do you define the C* tensor product in that case?

Answer (score 2):

Martin Brandenburg's answers gives a categorical proof using the full strength of Gelfand--Naimark.

One could also try to prove this more directly (using some of the ingredients that come into the proof of Gelfand--Naimark).

There is an obvious morphism $C(X)\otimes C(Y) \to C(X\times Y).$  (Here I just mean the usual tensor product.)  Now the Stone--Weierstrass approximation theorem
will show that this has dense image, and hence that the map from the completed tensor product $C(X) \widehat{\otimes} C(Y) \to C(X\times Y)$ is surjective.
[Added: actually, even this surjectivity isn't clear, as Martin Brandenburg
points out in a comment.]

To show that you get an isomorphism will take a little more work.

---

Another approach would be to show that the natural map $C(X) \widehat{\otimes} V \to C(X,V)$ (continuous $V$-valued functions) is an isomorphism for some class
of Banach spaces $V$, and to then apply this with $V = C(Y)$, and then use
that $C(X,C(Y)) = C(X\times Y).$  Off the top of my head, though, I'm not
sure how generally this formula holds.  (I don't see why it wouldn't hold for
arbitrary $V$, but I've not thought much about it, and my experience with this
kind of question comes from the $p$-adic context, where things are normally easier.)

Comment: I doubt that this "little more work" can be done directly, without repeating the categorical argument. Also notice that you have already used the universal property to construct $C(X) \widehat{\otimes} C(Y) \to C(X \times Y)$. How do you really show that it is surjective? Stone-Weierstrass only gives us that this map has a dense image. And how do you prove that it is injective? Notice that we cannot really write down the elements in the tensor product explicitly.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Dear Martin, All very good points.  Cheers,

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: P.S. I've added another possible approach, but again, I'm not sure whether it can really be carried out.  (The $p$-adic analogues of both my suggested approaches work, I think, but the $p$-adic case is easier to think about and work with, at least for me!)

Comment: Note that $C(X)\hat{\otimes} C(Y)$ need not be a C*-algebra. Indeed, $\ell_\infty \hat{\otimes} c$ contains a complemented copy of a Hilbert space. If it were a C*-algebra, it would be of the form $C(K)$ for some $K$, whereas $C(K)$-spaces have the Dunford-Pettis property, so they cannot have complemented reflexive subspaces.

Comment: Dear Tomek, Thanks very much for this remark.  Am I right then that there is an error in Martin Brandenburg's argument?  (I guess the gap is that he doesn't actually check that $C^*$-axiom for the tensor product, and your example shows that it won't always hold, if I understand correctly.)   I would like to edit my answer to reflect your comment, but I want to make sure that I understand it correctly first.  If you could reply to confirm (or not!) that I'm understanding things correctly that would be great!  Best wishes,

Comment: The maximal tensor product $\otimes_{\mathrm{max}}$ is a $C^*$-algebra. Perhaps my notation $\widehat{\otimes}$ was not good.